# custom environment variable - argocd

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argoproj, argocd

There are build environment variables (https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/build-environment/) so can inject something like `$ARGOCD_APP_NAME` on the application/helm yaml file and it resolves to the actual value.

Is there a way we can set custom environment variables so it can be resolved on the argocd application yaml file?

For example on below argocd application yaml, need to set the ENV value so helm can know which values.yaml to use.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
    ...
spec:
    ...
    source:
       ...
        helm:
            valueFiles:
                - values_${ENV}.yaml
```

Comment: did you ever get this working ?

Comment: Hi @Sirex, so we ended up having different branches per environment, like the targetRevision field under Application yaml refers to the branch name.  This way also, to promote changes from one env to another, we could just raise a pull request from one env branch to another.

Answer (score 2):

It's a late answer, but you can. You can use the plugin field to add the ENV variables in the application level, the example follows:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  source:
    plugin:
      env:
          - name: ENV_VARIABLE
            value: ENV_VALUE
```

Comment: When using Helm this won't going to work. Error form ArgoCD:

rpc error: code = Unknown desc = multiple application sources defined: Helm,Plugin